# empty div minimum text height

Tags: css

How to give an empty div a minimum height equal to the text height?!

In this example there are multiple label/value pairs.. And some values are empty

How to give the empty value container a minimum height equal to the text height?

## Attention

This is NOT a table layout.. Each label/value have different width

## jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/p2ekqomj/9/

## code

```
<div>
    <div class="input_label" style="width:80px">
        <div class="input_label label">Label 1</div>
        <div class="input_label_value">Value 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="input_label" style="width:100px">
        <div class="input_label label">Label 2</div>
        <div class="input_label_value"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="input_label" style="width:50px">
        <div class="input_label label">Label 3</div>
        <div class="input_label_value"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="input_label" style="width:60px">
        <div class="input_label label">Label 4</div>
        <div class="input_label_value"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="input_label" style="width:80px">
        <div class="input_label label">Label 5</div>
        <div class="input_label_value">Value 5</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="input_label" style="width:120px">
        <div class="input_label label">Label 6</div>
        <div class="input_label_value"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.input_label {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.input_label.label {
    font-size:11px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need to...if all you are after is alignment then you can do that like this - http://jsfiddle.net/p2ekqomj/2/

Comment: That really looks like a table layout, even if you do it with css - [see this example](http://jsfiddle.net/p2ekqomj/3/). I suggest you use the table.

Comment: @ paulie_d, this works.. but what if there a multiple on top of each other.. If a "line" of values are empty you have the same problem.. no space http://jsfiddle.net/p2ekqomj/5/

Answer (score 1):

Change the display property of `.input_label` from `inline-block` to `table-cell`:

```
.input_label {
    display:table-cell;
    padding:2px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/p2ekqomj/4/)**

Comment: This is same as he used table first place. He used wrong markup, wrong class attributes, everything is wrong because tabular data should be in tables.

Comment: @skobaljic - I have no idea what you're talking about. Where do you see that "he used table first place"? And while tables should be used for tabular data, using CSS table-cell styling is for any element. It's just styling and has no semantic value.

Comment: This is not a table.. each "cell" have different width

Comment: @clarkk - Are you commenting to me or skobaljic? If me I don't know what you mean that it's not a table since I never refers to your divs as a table. Also, where does the width you refer to figure into this? Please clarify.

Comment: Have updated my question with a better example with label/value pairs in multiple lines..

Comment: Your Fiddle example behavior is exactly same as table layout - cells won't go into multiple rows. So, why would you use css there to create something that already exists, just simply do `<table>...` My [example](http://jsfiddle.net/p2ekqomj/3/) above has more sense to play with css.